# Stretchable Header View in UITableView with dynamical height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, constraints

How can I manage the height of the TableViewHeader based on the lines of an UILabel?

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@Anantha1992/stretchable-header-view-in-uitableview-swift-5-ios-ee1c371f488e) but I can't manage the header height dynamically.

In the guide it is fixed to a fixed size to which I tried to add the height of the label but it doesn't work.

I would prefer to use a tableview and not a scrollview as the data is populated dynamically.

I also tried to modify the constraints of the label dynamically, but when scroll the view of the label is stretched and not the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 25;
```

After that just give correct constrains for the headerView . That's it! No need to implement `heightForHeaderInSection`